# Bootstrap 4 navbar error with dropdown menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I just uploaded a test page When you click on them you don't get directed to the album page link. The page blinks and jumps quickly. Here is the live test page to see what I mean. [Here is the live test page to see what I mean](https://johnandcricket.com/test.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>TEST JohnandCricket.com ALBUM 1</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=jquery.fancybox.min.css><link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"><meta name="author" content="John Samonas"><meta name="robots" content="index, follow"><meta name="description" content=""><!-- Open Graph general (Facebook, Pinterest & Google+) --><meta name="og:title" content="JohnandCricket.com"><meta name="og:description" content=""><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5"><meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"></head><body><header><img class="banner img-fluid lazy mx-auto" src="images/jcb.jpg" alt="John and Cricket banner"></header>

<div class="container-fluid">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom"><button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Photos</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="album1.html">Album 1</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="album2.html">Album 2</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="album3.html">Album 3</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="album4.html">Album 4</a></li>
</ul></li></ul></div></nav>

<div class="container">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 w-100">
<iframe style="min-height:100vh;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S8smZWM_dl8" title="YouTube video player" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</div><script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script defer src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-lazyload@12.0.0/dist/lazyload.min.js"></script><script>var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({ elements_selector: ".lazy" });</script><script defer  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script></body></html>
```

CSS:

```
body{color:#00008b;font-family:Georgia;font-size:22px}body,.masthead{background:url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;background-size:cover}.masthead img{width:100%;height:180px;max-height:200px;height:auto}.container{background-color:snow;border-radius:2rem;margin:1.5rem auto;width:90%;}.navbar-custom{background-color:#32de84}.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,.navbar-custom .navbar-text{text-decoration:none;color:#000}a.navbar-brand:link,a.navbar-brand:visited{color:#32de84;text-decoration:none;background-color:#000;border-radius:50%;padding:.5rem}a.navbar-brand:hover,a.navbar-brand:focus{color:red;text-decoration:none}.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link{text-decoration:none;color:#000}.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,.navbar-custom{text-decoration:none;color:#000}.nav-item .nav-link:hover{color:#000;background-color:#fff;border-radius:.5rem}.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu{background-color:#32de84}.navbar-custom .dropdown-item{text-decoration:none;color:#000}.navbar-custom .dropdown-item:hover,.navbar-custom .dropdown-item:focus{text-decoration:none;color:#000;background-color:#fff}@media (max-width:767px){nav.navbar{max-height:100vh;overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch}}.navbar-toggler{border-color:rgb(255,255,255)}.navbar-toggler-icon{color:#fff}.navbar-toggler-icon:hover{background:#fff}span.navbar-toggler-icon{background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")}@media (max-width:767px){nav.navbar{max-height:100vh;overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch}}#bgXXX{background:url(../images/bg.jpg);background-size:cover;background:no-repeat center center fixed}a{color:#00008b;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:focus{color:#036;text-decoration:underline}a{color:#00008b;text-decoration:underline;a:hover{color:#036;text-decoration:underline}}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{color:#00008b}.img-fixed{padding-bottom:5px}.carousel-item .img-fluid{width:90%;height:auto}.carousel-item a{display:block;width:100%;height:auto}.carousel-control-prev{color:background-color:#3F0;margin-left:-1rem;z-index:10;text-decoration:none}.carousel-control-next{color:background-color:#3F0;;margin-right:-1rem;z-index:10;text-decoration:none}.carousel-controls a:hover{color:#00cc00;z-index:10;text-decoration:none}
.carousel-control-prev:hover{color:#458B00;text-decoration:none}
.carousel-control-next:hover{color:#458B00;text-decoration:none}.embed-responsive{width:90%;height:auto}#scroll{position:fixed;right:10px;bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem;background-color:#3F0;text-indent:-9999px;display:none;-webkit-border-radius:50%;-moz-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;opacity:.75}#scroll span{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-8px;margin-top:-12px;height:0;width:0;border:8px solid transparent;border-bottom-color:#fff}#scroll:hover{background-color:#3C0;opacity:1;filter:"alpha(opacity=100)";-ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=100)"}
```

I checked the code on https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea and it passed. Document checking completed. No errors or warnings to show.

Comment: The dropdown menu doesn't come out for me for some reason when i go to the page...

Comment: I used the navbar code from the official Bootstrap site too. I used a navbar and just deleted a few of the <li class="nav-item"> lines  You are correct, you don't see the drop down, my mistake..

Comment: I know what the problem is... give me a second, and i will write you the code... i think i got it

Comment: should I add the entire page's html in my original post?

Comment: You can... And css also if there is some

Comment: first of all `<script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` should go before others so move it up before bootstrap line

there are console errors like: 

`bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6`

Comment: https://johnandcricket.com/jquery.fancybox.min.css is not found, so the path should be fixed to get styles working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That occurs because you are using Bootstrap 4, but the button link responsible for the toggling of the `.dropdown-menu` submenu is currently using the associated Bootstrap 5 data toggle attribute instead.

Bootstrap [4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#navbarSupportedContent) versus [5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar#navbarSupportedContent):

```
data-toggle vs data-bs-toggle
```

This should fix it:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" ... data-toggle=" ...>Photos</a>
```

Bootstrap 5 uses your current attribute:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" ... data-bs-toggle=" ...>Photos</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe when I originally changed the code from BS5 to 4 that I missed that.

Comment: @mlegg That's easy to miss :)

Comment: especially with my brain. I have secondary progressive MS for 23 years now,  at the end stage. I'm just trying to be a good friend before things get worse...

Comment: @mlegg Sorry to hear that. Feel free to ask me incase you face problems like this one in the future